# Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, typedef

i am getting the following Error while compiling my code:

> Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value

I've already read some other articles about that Problem in stackoverflow but i can't solve that behavior.

I have a Header file with two typedefs:

```
typedef struct{
    int32_t a;
    int32_t b;
    int32_t c;
}mydefone;

#ifndef _my_def_one
#define _my_def_one
    extern mydefone MyDefOne;
#endif

typedef struct{
    int32_t header;
    mydefone definition;
}mydeftwo;

#ifndef _my_def_two
#define _my_def_two
    extern mydeftwo MyDefTwo;
#endif
```

Now i am trying to use those two external definitions in my .c file and link them to each other like this:

```
mydefone MyDefOne = {1,2,3};
mydeftwo MyDefTwo = {567,MyDefOne};
```

and my Compiler throws the mentioned error for my MyDefTwo.

I know that usually i dont Need the Header solution in this example right now but later i Need to use those variables (same copy) in another c file just by implementing that Header.

thanks in advance!
ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyDefOne` is not a valid initializer. You should use next:

```
mydefone MyDefOne = {1,2,3};
mydeftwo MyDefTwo = {567,{1,2,3}};
```

or utilize macro to guarantee that the same values are used for both initializations:

```
#define MY_INITIALIZER {1,2,3}

mydefone MyDefOne = MY_INITIALIZER;
mydeftwo MyDefTwo = {567, MY_INITIALIZER};
```

Comment: i dont know how to mark questions as Solutions yet but this one is it for me